# How to perform action on swipe up on a card in Android Wear

Tags: android, swipe, wear-os

I'm trying to make some functionality to a card. If you have a few cards, you can swipe them left/right to move to a next card. Actually, when you are trying to swipe up/down, card is moving in that direction, but there is no action on that gestures.

Is it possible to make a action for up/down swipe (something like onClick, but swipe)?

E.g. i would like to run an app on handheld, if there is a swipe-up action on a card on wearable.